# Scala type error for cyclically referenced traits

Tags: scala, types, compiler-errors, cyclic-reference

I'm having trouble getting this code to work. I want to make a trait that allows a class that inherits it to have "children", but apparently, `Child`'s `setParent` method wants a `P`, but gets a `Parent[P, C]` instead.

```
package net.fluffy8x.thsch.entity

import scala.collection.mutable.Set

trait Parent[P, C <: Child[C, P]] {
  protected val children: Set[C]
  def register(c: C) = {
    children += c
    c.setParent(this) // this doesn't compile
  }
}

trait Child[C, P <: Parent[P, C]] {
  protected var parent: P
  def setParent(p: P) = parent = p
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use self types to indicate that `this` is `P` and not `Parent[P, C]`. This will also require extra bounds `P <: Parent[P, C]` and `C <: Child[C, P]`

```
trait Parent[P <: Parent[P, C], C <: Child[C, P]] { this: P =>
  protected val children: scala.collection.mutable.Set[C]
  def register(c: C) = {
    children += c
    c.setParent(this)
  }
}

trait Child[C <: Child[C, P], P <: Parent[P, C]] { this: C =>
  protected var parent: P
  def setParent(p: P) = parent = p
}
```